# Strange values in an array - after I change them they remain the same

Tags: c#, database

Here is my code:

```
var items = tableInDatabase.All("WHERE [Order] > " + order);
foreach (var i in items.ToArray())
{
    i.Order = 7;
}
tableInDatabase.Save(items.ToArray());
```

However, when the breakpoint comes to the last line (after the foreach loop), every element of items has an order the same as before (not 7). Why is this happening?
While still in the loop, i has an order of 7.

I'm using Massive, and this is the example from its official page:

```
var table = new Products();
var drinks = table.All("WHERE CategoryID = 8");
foreach(var item in drinks.ToArray()){
    item.CategoryID = 12;
}
table.Save(drinks.ToArray());
```

I also tried:

```
foreach (var i in items.ToArray())
{
    tableInDatabase.Update(i, i.Id);
}
```

And nothing.

The return type od tableInDatabase is the class TableInDatabase. This is the definition:

```
public TableInDatabase() : base(connectionString, "System.Data.SqlClient", "TableInDatabase", "Id") { }
```

Comment: what is the return type of tableInDatabase.All?

Comment: @ErenErsönmez I edited the question. See its ending.

Comment: What is the type of `i` in `foreach`?

Comment: You posted a constructor definition. And that gives us nothing. We need class definition at least.

Comment: @GrzegorzWilczura That is the only thing in the class - the constructor.

Comment: Scree, that's a know issue/bug in the massive example, see my answer

Comment: @Habib.OSU But your answer doesn't solve anything/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this code:

```
var items = tableInDatabase.All("WHERE [Order] > " + order);
var array = items.ToArray();
foreach (var i in array)
{
    i.Order = 7;
}
tableInDatabase.Save(array);
```

Comment: The code works for the other columns in the table, but not for Order. Maybe because it's a keyword?

Answer (score 0):

`ToArray()` creates a new copy as said by Romil, In your case since you are using [Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive), you can probably do what Adam has said, but that option creates two variable. You can try the following.

```
var items = tableInDatabase.All("WHERE [Order] > " + order).ToArray();
foreach (var i in items)
{
    i.Order = 7;
}
tableInDatabase.Save(items);
```

This is a known issue with Massive example and has been reported [here](https://github.com/robconery/massive/issues/84)

Comment: @Srcee, my bad, forgot to change the last line, it should be items not items.ToArray()

Comment: @Srcee, batch updates with Massive is buggy, check out this post https://github.com/robconery/massive/pull/85, you may have to use ToList instead of ToArray, or you may post the problem on Massive forum

Comment: Maybe the problem is that Order is a keyword?

Comment: Actually yes it is, because with the same code, when I update another column, it works.

Comment: @Srcee, Order is a keyword in SQL server, I think it has to do with that, Order is not a keyword in C#